# Jooq 3.14.1 fetchLazy with postgres fetching all rows

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I am new to jooq and trying to use [fetchLazy](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.16/manual/sql-execution/fetching/lazy-fetching/) with postgres.

I modified the data access code as mentioned in this [article](https://medium.com/@tejozarkar/configure-jooq-with-spring-boot-and-postgresql-c362e41722b9) like below

```
// BookService.java
public List<Book> getBooks(){
    final List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultQuery<BookRecord> resQuery = context.selectFrom(Tables.BOOK).fetchSize(2);
    transactionRunner.readOnlyTransaction(() -> {
        try(final Cursor<BookRecord> bookRecords = resQuery.fetchLazy()) {
            while (bookRecords.hasNext()) {
                List<Book> into = bookRecords.fetch().into(Book.class);
                System.out.println("Num Records: " + into.size());
                books.addAll(into);
            }
        }
    });
    return books;
}
```

My transaction code looks like below -

```
public class TransactionalRunner {
  private final PlatformTransactionManager manager;

  public void readOnlyTransaction(Runnable fn) {
    var template = new TransactionTemplate(manager);
    template.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED);
    template.execute(
        transactionStatus -> {
          fn.run();
          return null;
        });
  }
}
```

For testing, I have added 4 records in database. I am getting all 4 records in the single fetch even though `fetchSize` is set to 2.

```
Num Records: 4
```

All the modified code is placed in [github](https://github.com/debraj-spotnana/JooqSpringBootPostgreSQLDemo).

Can someone let me know what is going wrong?

- Jooq Version 3.14.1

Postgres is running as docker

```
docker run --name tuk-temp -p 58704:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres postgres
```

Comment: The `ResultQuery.fetchSize(N)` flag just tells the JDBC driver to cache `N` rows on the JDBC side. It doesn't affect how you fetch data via the jOOQ API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size needs to be specified in `fetchNext`.

```
// BookService.java
public List<Book> getBooks(){
    final List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultQuery<BookRecord> resQuery = context.selectFrom(Tables.BOOK).fetchSize(2);
    transactionRunner.readOnlyTransaction(() -> {
        try(final Cursor<BookRecord> bookRecords = resQuery.fetchLazy()) {
            while (bookRecords.hasNext()) {
                List<Book> into = bookRecords.fetchNext(2).into(Book.class);
                System.out.println("Num Records: " + into.size());
                books.addAll(into);
            }
        }
    });
    return books;
}
```